# C# comboBox without dropDown

Tags: c#, combobox

I have ordinary combobox and I want to prevent any changes on it, so I want to make it not show dropdown. Is it possible?

I've tried changing `dropDownStyle` to simple, but then it shows list of items below.

Comment: If you don't want the user to change it, why would you want it to be a ComboBox to begin with?

Comment: do you want to prevent user to write something in the combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to create readonly `TextBox` over the combo, wirh exact size and font of the combo, so the user possibly will not notice any difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to allow any changes on the control than I think you should set its Enabled property to false
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to allow user to do anything with combobox you can use this code in the constructor

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.Enabled = false;  
}
```

else if you want to prevent user from writing anything in the combobox to select the items in combobox you can use this code

```
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; 
}
```