# Winforms - Stop Dropdown of Combobox during DropDown event

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need to implement a `ComboBox`, which acts as follows:

When Click on the `ComboBox`, the client calling API method and updates the combobox items with the response.

My problem is, when I have 0 results - I want the `ComboBox` not to open (It has 0 items).

Is there a way to do that?
This is my current code:L

```
private void Combo_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Private method which addes items to the combo, and returns false if no itmes were added
    if (!AddItemsToComboBox())
    {
        // This is not working
        Combo.DroppedDown = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's happening when your code runs? Can we see `AddItemsToComboBox`? And since it returns a bool you can just do `Combo.DroppedDown = AddItemsToComboBox();`

Comment: Even if AddItemsToComboBox will do return false; 
DroppedDown = false don't stop to comboBox to open.
And also sender.DroppedDown is false...

Comment: The native Windows control does not support cancellation, the expectation is that you'll set the Enabled property to *false* when the combobox is useless.  But you'll have to find a smarter way to populate it of course.

Comment: How about just disabling it when there is no data?

Comment: Also why are you populating the combobox when they click on it? There's got to be a better time in the code to fill it. Then as @danish suggested you can just disable it then, before they try to open it.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567331/c-sharp-combobox-without-dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `DropDownHeight` as small as possible (1). For example:

```
  int iniHeight;
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        iniHeight = Combo.DropDownHeight;
  } 

  private void Combo_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        Combo.DropDownHeight = (AddItemsToComboBox() ? iniHeight : 1);
  }
```

Comment: If I don't keep the iniHeight and just write "1000", it will do the max, no? (My limit is around 20 items...)

Comment: @Shkolar This is just a sample code to transmit the idea; you can implement it in many different ways. The whole point of my answer is that by setting DrowDownHeight to 1 you can get what you are looking for (although the drowndown menu does not disappear completely, the user would think so).